# can't create IAM access key via bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to rotate AWS IAM access keys via bash script.

I am able to deactivate and delete access keys that are there. But after the last key is deleted and even after a 30 second sleep command, I still get this error trying to create the new key:

```
An error occurred (LimitExceeded) when calling the CreateAccessKey operation: Cannot exceed quota for AccessKeysPerUser: 2
```

This is my code:

```
        echo "Deleting AWS user access key: $user_access_key1"
        aws iam delete-access-key --access-key-id "$user_access_key1" --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile "$aws_key"
        sleep 2
        # Check if key still exists
        aws iam list-access-keys --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile "$aws_key" --output text --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].[AccessKeyId,Status]' | sed -e '1d')
        sleep 30
        #Create new keys
        new_keys=( $(aws iam create-access-key --user-name "$user_name" --profile="$aws_env" | jq -r '.AccessKey[] | (.SecretAccessKey, .AccessKeyId)') )
```

I'm able to verify that the previous key is gone after the script deletes it. So why am I not able to create a new key after deleting the last one?

Comment: How about trying a very long sleep? Just to rule out the eventual consistency of the API

Comment: You are being rate limited. You are exceeding the number of CreateAccessKey operations per time-period that AWS allows. Also, what you are doing is not normal from the viewpoint of automated security software (AI). While learning AWS try to stay away from testing things that trigger security events.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification. That does make sense. However I was testing my script in a LAB environment. We are allowed to experiment there. I'll keep that in mind going forward however. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnHanley In my case I was exceeding the quantity of access keys; I'd made an old one inactive while setting up a new one, so had 2 already. Nothing to do with rate limiting. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-limits.html